# how to avoid form resets automatically on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit

The Source code is below. When i press the submit button. the alert message is shown but immediately after that the form resets all text fieds and i have written an autocomplete jquery for from and to field which doesnt work after reset.

Can anyone please guide me to avoid this reset.

```
enter code here
   <div data-role="content" >
        <form action="#" name="myform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
            From:<input id="from" type="text" name="From-busstop">
            To:<input id= "to" type="text" name="To-busstop">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["myform"]["from"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="") {
            alert("From must be filled out");
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

oh sorry. i was actually changing the content to be more readible..
i have update the code which i am trying to build

Comment: `var x = document.forms["busroute"]["from"].value;` what is `busroute` here? i don't find in the code.

Comment: try adding event.preventdefault();

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2dho588u/

Comment: okay let me try preventdefault(); i had tried earlier it didnt work though.

Comment: @adeneo i tried this .jsfiddle.net/2dho588u but if you check that code in a browser the content is reset on submit

Comment: Not in my browser, if you leave `from` empty so the alert fires, the contents of `to` is still there after the alert, anything else would be strange, and indicate that you're doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: @adeneo oh i see it works fine. then it must somewhere else that has gone wrong in the code

Comment: Thanks guys for the Help . I used   $('#submit').on('click',function(e) 
&    e.preventDefault();
  But now i am stuck with another thing. The Submit button remains pressed. Is there a way to unpress it.

Comment: Please answer this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943169/how-to-trigger-unpress-on-a-button-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be here:

```
var x = document.forms["busroute"]["from"].value;
```

i don't think the selector is correct, as i see there is no property in the form element with `["busroute"]`.

So the solution is as you have `id` attribute applied on your form element then better to make a selector with it like below, and make sure to `.trim()/$.trim(x)` the value to have any blank spaces:

```
var x = $("#from").val(); // if you have jQuery
```

or

```
var x = document.getElementById("from").value; // with js
```

or in modern js:

```
var x = document.querySelector("#from").value; // with js
```

Comment: I have tried var x = document.getElementById("from").value; still the submit resets the content and changed code as per ur suggestion

Comment: @mushahidalam then you might have some js error in your page.